# How to read zipfile from stdin

Tags: python, zip, stdin

I'm trying to solve reading a zipfile from `stdin` in python, but I keep getting issues. What I want is to be able to run `cat test.xlsx | python3 test.py` and create a valid `zipfile.ZipFile` object without first writing a temporary file if possible.

My initial approach was this, but `ZipFile` complained the file is not seekable,

```
import sys
import zipfile

zipfile.ZipFile(sys.stdin)
```

so I changed it around, but now it complains that this is not a valid zip file:

```
import io
import sys
import zipfile

zipfile.ZipFile(io.StringIO(sys.stdin.read()))
```

Can this be solved without writing the zip to a temporary file?

Comment: Obligatory, [don't abuse your cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: Not that I don't abuse it often, but this was now for simulating `in | ziphandler`  where in comes from aerc (reading an xslx attachment in the pager).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip files are binary data, not UTF-8 encoded text. You won't be able to read the file into a `str` with `sys.stdin.read()` without immediately hitting a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte ...` error.

Instead, you can access the underlying binary [`buffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.buffer) object to read stdin as raw `bytes`. Pair that with [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to get an in-memory seekable [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object:

```
zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(sys.stdin.buffer.read()))
```

Alternatively, if you provide a seekable stdin (for example, [by redirecting stdin instead of streaming from a pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)), you can operate on  `sys.stdin.buffer` directly:

```
zipfile.ZipFile(sys.stdin.buffer)
```

paired with something like

```
python3 test.py <test.xlsx
```

If you care to, you can select between the two depending on whether stdin is seekable by querying the IO object's [`seekable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seekable) method:

```
if sys.stdin.buffer.seekable():
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.stdin.buffer)
else:
    buffer = io.BytesIO(sys.stdin.buffer.read())
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)

print(zip_file.filelist)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely comprehensive!

Comment: Tbh, I should've added you as a co-author on the commit :D https://github.com/ferdinandyb/xlsx2csv/commit/8a4c028c7db45fe30247a9f8f58d50255267179c if you give me your name/address I can still do so.